# NoData Cells getting zero

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have rasterfiles and I'm using Extract Multi Values to Point but there are some parts of two layers aren't overlap. Normally, these points should get -999 or something like this? But my NoData points getting zero and this could be a major problem because I couldn't understand which one is real zero and which one is NoData.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Somehow when you use **Extract Multivalues to point** these cells get zero but if you use **extract values to points** they will get -999.